# Fit table height to page

Tags: tables, adjustbox

Hey I want to put a table to my latex document in such a way that it fill the rest of the place on a given page. How can I do that with for example adjustbox? The following works if I want to fit textwidth:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
```

but how can I do analogically for textheight? Because the table may starts in the middle of the page and I want to do this in such a way that it will fit the second half od the page.

Comment: Never use \adjustbox for tables – it leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: So what can I use?

Comment: you can change the value of `\arraystretch`, for instance.

Comment: Vertically stretching a table only to fill the page is the wrong approach. Put the table in a bottom float (e, g.: `\begin{table}[b]...\caption{My ttable}\label{mytable}\end{table}`) and then the possible gap between text and table will be filled with the next after the table  without deforming the table. Even if this move the table a bit or a lot (for instance, latex think is better move the table to next page)  a reference in text (e.g. "`see table \ref{mytable}`" )  is preferable  to distort the table  at Greco's style.